# How to make Karma watch coffeescript files

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, karma-runner

I have a web app that's written in Coffeescript and that I'm testing with Karma.  My tests are written and I'm now writing code to make the tests pass.

At the moment, every time I change my code, I need to rerun my tests manually by typing `grunt karma` in a terminal.  Is there a way to set up karma to automatically rerun my tests whenever my .coffee files change?

Here's my `karma.conf.js`:

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath: '',

preprocessors: {
  '**/*.coffee': ['coffee']
},

coffeePreprocessor: {
  // options passed to the coffee compiler
  options: {
    bare: true,
    sourceMap: false
  },
  // transforming the filenames
  transformPath: function(path) {
    return path.replace(/\.coffee$/, '.js')
  }
},


// testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
frameworks: ['jasmine'], //,'requirejs'],

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'app/bower_components/**/*.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.coffee',
  '.tmp/scripts/**/*.js'
],

// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [],

// web server port
port: 8080,

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true, // change by davebenson. was false

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun: false
});
};
```

Comment: What does your config file look like?

Comment: I suppose you don't transpile changed coffee files into js automatically when you run `grunt karma`. Based on posted configuration, karma watches all coffee files inside `test/spec` but only js files in other places. I will not detect changes in `app/scripts/*.coffee` for example. Try to create [mcve] maybe and post it on github?